# Why is razor is adding quotation marks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I'm playing around with my _layout.cshtml, I want to put a custom string in my footer. It should be easy, right?

```
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        I'm a custom string.
    </div>
</footer>
```

When I look at it in my browser's dev tools it comes out as:

```
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
       " I'm a custom string. "
     </div>
</footer>
```

It does this if I wrap the string in a span, paragraph, or anything else. I've tried putting the string into the viewbag and rendering it with various `@Html` methods to no avail.

Where are these quotation marks coming from, and how can I avoid them?

Edit: With further experimentation, it appears to happen when the string would overflow a parent container. Still not sure how to prevent it from happening.

Comment: I suspect this is just how devtools show this. To confirm, use a http debugger to see what's really sent over the wire.

Comment: try wrapping it in some kind of tag... ex: <p>I'm a custom string.</p>

Comment: Viewing source does show it without the quotes. Interesting. Thanks!